# Found an OfficeDraw file with shapes. Can the shapes be used without continuous copy-and-paste?

Tags: shapes, openoffice.org

I downloaded an OpenOffice Draw document with shapes I want to use (for drawing Apache Camel diagrams). I'm not very familiar with Draw, but I've used Visio; in Visio, there was a kind of file in which you could find/put shapes, then use to create drawings from those shapes. The shapes appeared in a panel left of and smaller than the drawing, and you could drag a shape from that panel to the drawing to put an instance of that shape on your drawing; the original shape remained on the smaller panel.

I think Visio called the file that held the shapes you could use a "template"; Draw has templates, but I haven't found a reference to them holding shapes to drag onto a drawing. I've tried looking it up, but am hampered by not knowing what terms Draw uses for these things. Can someone tell me whether this is possible in Draw, and what things I should look up help on? I hate to read a whole manual to find out how to use one feature, without even knowing if the feature exists...

--

I'm sorry, I should have done better describing what I have tried. The file holding the shapes is an odg file; it opens fine as a document, and the program allows me to save it as a template, but the behavior of being a collection of shapes that I can drag onto a new drawing repeatedly, without having to copy a shape each time, is not there. That's the feature I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

My version (LO 5.2.3.3/openSuse) allows the creation of a new shape gallery theme (see: `View>Clipart Gallery`), and the addition of various graphic format files to that theme.

Also, in context meni of a shape, I can `edit with external program`.

So, I guess, you can save the shape(s) in a file and add it to `My Shapes` theme.

There will be two new files in `~/.config/libreoffice/5/user/gallery` with the shape(s), to backup/restore (to a new installation) or distribution (to other computers).

**Edit** if your version of the office suite is lacking of that menu options, maybe you can extract the shapes from the `*.odg` file: unzip it and look for a custom `*.sdv` and `*.thm` file in the archive.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the effort. OfficeDraw does have "Tools / Gallery", and the Gallery does store graphics in a similar way. However, the document I've got that contains these shapes (an odg extension) doesn't seem to have any way to export the individual shapes, at least not from OfficeDraw. I've right-clicked, I've selected and attempted to use File / Export, but I haven't found any way to export the individual graphics. I can move them one at a time to the gallery within OfficeDraw, but there are 50 of them, and after I move one I have to right-click it and set its name. Still hoping...